# How to disable resizability of Sidebar NavigationView in SwiftUI (MacOS)?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, navigationview

I'm new to Swift and I've been trying to build an app and learn as I go. I have a NavigationView that holds a List as a sidebar that renders the content as the user clicks. The bar between these two panes can be grabbed to allow the user to resize. This seems to be the default behavior of a NavigationView. I'm trying to find a way to disable it because I don't want the user to resize the sidebar.

```swift
struct Sidebar: View {
    var body: some view {
        List {
            NavigationLink("First section", destination: FirstSection)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 150, maxWidth: 150)
    }
}
```

I also couldn't find a way to tell Swift that I want my List view to have a dynamic width that just fits the content. Just like it's done with CSS `width: fit-content;`

In the picture below, you can see that I was able to resize the sidebar to be almost half the screen. How to disable this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Also would be interesting to prevent collapsing the sidebar entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do found a solution for that all you have to do is to set the destination width so that the sidebar can't be resized to the destination view for example like that ## consider the firstSection() as a View ##

**Here the app main start**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct macosTestApp: App {
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        NavigationView {
            SideBar()
        }.toolbar {
            // add the open/close sidebar navigation here
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                Button(action: toggleSidebar, label: { // 1
                    Image(systemName: "sidebar.leading")
                })
            }
           
         
            
        }.frame(minWidth: 800, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 600, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
    }
}
private func toggleSidebar() { // 2
    NSApp.keyWindow?.firstResponder?.tryToPerform(#selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:)), with: nil)
}

}
```

**Here the sidebar and the navigationView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SideBar: View {
@State var isActiveView:Bool = true
var body: some View {
    
    List {
        NavigationLink("First section", destination: FirstSection().frame(minWidth: 750, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 600, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center),isActive: $isActiveView)
    }
    
}

}

struct FirstSection: View {

var body: some View {
    
    Text("Hello")
}

}

struct text_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    SideBar()
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i was able to do it, in a weird way,
the first thing was to create an NSViewControllerRepresentable
so i was able to wrap an NSViewController in which i generate a 1X1 square view
because the NSViewController has the complete life cycle
i was able to write the code inside viewDidDisappear()
and toggle back the sidebar